# Having trouble using Visual Studio Webserver to host a WCF SOAP endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, soap

I have a known working web service which is configured as a SOAP and REST binding. I can call it with a  test harness and I can see the SOAP POST's going to and then the SOAP response all good.

However when I try and host the service in visual studio 2010 Cassini I get the following behaviour:

1) When calling endpoint as REST and using the WebChannelFactory class the service works.
2) When calling the endpoint as SOAP and using the ChannelFactory class the service throws an error and I get a 400 response. (The error is below).
3) When calling the endpoint as SOAP and using a c# SOAP reference the service works.

Confusing no?

Im wondering is it something to do with the fact that I have used a port number for the Cassini version?

---

just before people start telling me to host in IIS I really need to get this working in Cassini as its part of a tutorial on WCF

---

Here is the raw HTTP request that doesnt work (when called against a working IIS deployment and the faulty Visual Studio webserver.

IIS WORKING:

```
POST http://api.dev.videolibraryserver.com/VLSContentService.svc/soap/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IVLSContentService/EchoWithGet"
Host: api.dev.videolibraryserver.com
Content-Length: 180
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><EchoWithGet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><message>Hello World!</message></EchoWithGet></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

VISUAL STUDIO (CASSINI) - NOT WORKING:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:52587/VLSContentService.svc//soap HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IVLSContentService/EchoWithGet"
Host: 127.0.0.1:52587
Content-Length: 180
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><EchoWithGet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><message>Hello World!</message></EchoWithGet></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

THE ERROR RESPONSE WHEN USING CASSINI

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Thu, 23 Jun 2011 10:42:09 GMT
Content-Length: 1209
Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Connection: Close

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bad Request</title>
        <style>
            body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: 8pt;color:black;} 
            p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
            b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
            h1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
            h2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
            pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: 8pt}
            .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
            .version {color: gray;}
            .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
            .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><h1>Server Error in '/' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></h1>

            <h2> <i>HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request.</i> </h2></span>

            <hr width=100% size=1 color=silver>

            <b>Version Information:</b>&nbsp;ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0

            </font>

    </body>
</html>
```

THE .NET EXCEPTION (although irrelevant as no response returned from server)

```
C:\Users\Peter Heard\Desktop\TestClient\Debug>TestClient.exe "http://ipv4.fiddle
r:52587/VLSContentService.svc/" "Hello World!" 2


***************************
About to call SOAP web service interface TestSOAPUsingChannelFactory()
There was an errorSystem.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server retur
ned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The
 remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpCha
nnelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResp
onse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factor
y, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpCha
nnelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeS
pan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message messag
e, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean on
eway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan tim
eout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCall
Message methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage req
Msg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgDa
ta, Int32 type)
   at IVLSContentService.EchoWithGet(String message)
   at TestClient.Program.TestSOAPUsingChannelFactory() in C:\Repositories\VideoL
ibraryServer\trunk\prototypes\Hml_Api_Wcf\TestClient\Program.cs:line 96
   at TestClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Repositories\VideoLibraryServ
er\trunk\prototypes\Hml_Api_Wcf\TestClient\Program.cs:line 47
```

************Update**************************

Whilst the answer to this question was correct. My testing wasnt. I actually tried to pass a '//' in the url for the IIS and Cassini and it didnt work for Cassini. Obviously IIS is a bit more robust when handling quotes. The comments below talk about this but I thought i would update the answer.

Comment: I was genuinely trying to help.  I have traveled this road before.  Sorry if it came across as being arrogant.

Comment: Fair enought mate I appreciate Ive been an 'MVC question machine' the last couple of days but Im the only developer here so im always stuck seem to have the hang of it now anyway. Im trying to write a tutorial on what I have found like using a debugger to see whats going on. Ive also answered some questions. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of your "not working" request has an extra slash in the URL:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:52587/VLSContentService.svc//soap HTTP/1.1
                                                  ^
```

Comment: Your right! couldnt see the woods for the trees. Was exactly the same code and the url I put in the test harness was the same, not sure why the request puts the extra slash in will find out. Guess ive got used to looking at double slashes in the debugger. Thankyou!!! :-)

Comment: This is really wierd but I changed the IIS one to double quotes and amazingly it still works. I think IIS can deal with double slashes and Cassini can't.!

Comment: That is interesting. I don't know exactly what the HTTP spec says (perhaps double slashes are actually acceptable), but my guess is the IIS team decided to go ahead and accept some requests that are invalid, whereas there was no need to go to the extra effort in Cassini.

Comment: I will usually scrub URLs replacing '\' with '/' and then "//" with "/"... as I have seen similar issues on various servers.. I tend to be very judicious with url casing as well.